# retrieving a pointer to an object connected to a known object via DDX_Control

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a CStatic object and another object( a report ), which is connected to the Static object using DDX_Control( pDX, IDC_CHILD_WINDOW_HOLDER, m_xtpTabControl );

I can get a pointer to the Static object.
The problem is that I can not access my real object(m_xtpTabControl).

So, is there a way to get a pointer to it?

Just:

```
CWnd * pWnd = pWindow->GetDlgItem( IDC_CHILD_WINDOW_HOLDER );
```

pWnd is now a pointer to that object of class CStatic, not the class of m_xtpTabControl.

Comment: When you say the control is "connected", do you mean that the tab control is the parent of the static control?  And, what is the resource Id of the tab control?

Comment: @rrirower -> No, the static is just a frame in the dialog, where the Report is to be shown. The report object is doing the rest of the work.

Comment: What type of control is the report object?  Does it have a resource ID?

Comment: The report have no resource, otherwise i could get my pointer ... :)

Comment: But, how is the report object implemented?  Is it an activeX control?  Does it have a window handle?  Or, are you simply drawing on the dialog?  Some more code showing the actual relationship would be helpful.

Comment: It is object of class CXTPReportControl. You can find some info about XTP on the net. I am not sure if it is an ActiveX control. It derives CWnd. But that is not important for this question. Imagine you have DDX_Control( pDX, IDC_CHILD_WINDOW, m_pButton );, where m_pButton is from CButton class and IDC_CHILD_WINDOW is a CStatic and you have a pointer to that static object, how can you get a pointer to the m_pButton?

Comment: I took a quick look at the CodeJock [CXTPReportControl](http://read.pudn.com/downloads91/sourcecode/graph/texture_mapping/350577/Codejock%20Software/MFC/Xtreme%20Toolkit%20Pro%20v9.60/Include/ReportControl/XTPReportControl.h__.htm) and it would appear that you need to assign it a resource ID to create it, so, I'm not sure why you are having trouble with this?  Are you sure the CWnd that is returned is not for the control?

Comment: CXTPReportControl is an object from the dialog that holds the report control, so I can cast and access my member, but it is plan B, because it will break the rule, not to use my own classes in this program. It is an automation testing system, which avoids using the code from the application. I hope I`m clear ... :)

Comment: "that you need to assign it a resource ID to create it" -> it is a member of the dialog class, and it is created in the construction of the object. Then using DDX_Control it is somehow connected to the static control. I have a resource for the static, so I can retrieve a pointer to the static, but it is not the member ... because the member have some internal data, and the static have the same members, but not initialized ... :) I`m not sure if I`m missing something.

Comment: It seems like you're missing a lot. Generally the static is a placeholder for the location of the report. So in OnInitDialog the report is created at the location of the static, and the static is then destroyed. Is this application working at all? Is there any explicit initialization code for the report? If the report is created OK, just forget about the static and use &m_xtpTabControl to get a pointer to the report. There is no 'static is connected to report'. DDX_Control is used to associate a control with a dialog id to a member variable, that's it.

Comment: No Create() is called for m_xtpTabControl. By the way I found a solution - in OnInitDialog ::SetWindowLongPtr(GetDlgItem(IDC_CHILD_WINDOW_HOLDER)->GetSafeHwnd(), GWLP_USERDATA, (INT_PTR)&m_xtpTabControl);     Then I can get it with - GetWindowLongPtr(pWnd->GetDlgItem(IDC_CHILD_WINDOW_HOLDER)->GetSafeHwnd(), GWLP_USERDATA);    Sorry, I can not insert a new line in this text field ... :)  m_xtpTabControl is not registered as a window, it is only connected via DDX_Control() and that is the mistery here :). Thanks for the conversation :)

Comment: In addition, with Spy++ you can see a window with a class name - "Static" :) You can try it, I`m not sure whether only XTP controls can be used like that, now I have no time to try it with some standart control(like e.g. CButton) ...